# ¿Puedo meter un array entero dentro de una posición de otro array?

Tags: java

Estoy intentando meter el contenido de un array en una posición de otra array:

Este es el algoritmo que uso:

```
public Palabra[] leerPalabra() throws IOException {
    char[] nuevaPalabra = new char[20]; 
    Palabra[] Palabras = new Paraula[50];
    char[] aux = this.leerLinia().toCharArray();
    int j = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < Palabras.length; x++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < aux.length; i++) { 
            if (aux[i] != ' ') { 
                nuevaPalabra[j] = aux[i];
                j++;
            }
            Palabras[x] = new Palabra[nuevaPalabra];
        }
    }

    return Palabras;
}
```

El problema esta en la línea de: Palabras[x] = new Palabra[nuevaPalabra];
Primero me pone que un char[] no se puede convertir en un int.
Segundo que Palabra[] no se puede convertir en Palabra.

Entiendo lo que me dice, pero si yo le hago "Palabras[x]" no le estoy diciendo la x posición del array Palabras? Y en en el otro caso, si hago Palabra[nuevaPalabra] no le estoy diciendo que quiero que me meta el valor del Array "nuevaPalabra" en el Array Palabra[]?

Esta es mi clase Palabra:

public class Palabra {

```
private char[] letra;

public Palabra(char[] letra) {
    this.letra = letra;
}

public char[] getLetras() {
    return letra;
}

public void setLetras(char[] letra) {
    this.letra = letra;
}

public char primeraLetra(){
    return letra[0];
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    String letras = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < letra.length; i++) {
        letras += letra[i];
    }
    return letras;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Código relevante:

```
char[] nuevaPalabra = new char[20]; 
...
Palabras[x] = new Palabra[nuevaPalabra];
```

y

```
public class Palabra {
   public Palabra(char[] palabra) {
      ...
   }
   ...
}
```

Primero, `new Palabra[nuevaPalabra]` te declara un nuevo array de palabras, y la expresión dentro de los corchetes tiene que ser de tipo `int` (el tamaño del array).

`Palabras[x]` es una variable de tipo `Palabra`, no puedes asignar un array de `Palabra` a `Palabras[x]` (pero `Palabras`, sin el índice, sí es un array y lo podrías asignar).

Y en todo caso, viendo el constructor, lo que parece que quiere hacer quien escribió el código es crear no un array sino un objeto `Palabra` usando el constructor `Palabra(char[])`, pero se ve que en vez de llamar al constructor (con paréntesis) acaba creando un array (con corchetes).

Es decir:

```
Palabras[x] = new Palabra(nuevaPalabra);
```

Aparte, recomendaría que te fijases más en los identificadores:

- Los nombres de variables siempre usan camelCase, las clases empiezan por mayúscula (p.ej. `palabras[x] = new Palabra(nuevaPalabra);`).
- Los nombres deberían ayudarte a identificar qué es cada cosa (tienes una clase `Palabra` y una variable `nuevaPalabra`, pero `nuevaPalabra` NO es una instancia de `nuevaPalabra`).

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aportación, el objeto palabra lo he creado yo.
No entiendo mucho cuando me dices esto "Primero, new Palabra[nuevaPalabra] te declara un nuevo array de palabras, y la expresión dentro de los corchetes tiene que ser de tipo int (el tamaño del array)." Por que necesita un tipo int si es un array de chars?

Comment: Estimado @Pedro la respuesta a tu pregunta ¿"si hago Palabra[nuevaPalabra] no le estoy diciendo que quiero que me meta el valor del Array "nuevaPalabra" en el Array Palabra[]"? es un rotundo no. Me parece que estás interpretando mal muchas cosas.